# Запятая в предложении с деепричастным оборотом

Tags: пунктуация

Имеем перевод с отсутсвующим исходным текстом:

> Мы вознаграждаем авторов вопросов пересчитав репутацию!

Какой смысл имеет это предложение? Говорит ли оно только текущем моменте или о любом моменте во времени?

Нужно ли обособлять оборот "пересчитав репутацию" запятой?

Примечание. Возможная исходная фраза

> We’re rewarding the question askers & reputations are being recalculated! Read more.

Comment: Запятая перед этим деепричастным оборотом необходима, поскольку он в предложении только один да ещё и в самом конце предложения стоит. Правила и исключения: https://obrazovaka.ru/russkiy-yazyk/deeprichastnyjj-oborot-zapyatye — ваш оборот ни под одно из исключений не подпадает.

Comment: @YellowSky, имеет ли предложение смысл вообще? Оно мне как-то режет слух, но я не понимаю почему.

Comment: Кривоватое оно, хотя грамматически правильное: сперва пересчитали, а теперь этим награждаем. Просто в оригинале (We’re rewarding the question askers & reputations are being recalculated! — явно с этого переводили) предложение сложносочинённое, два действия одновременны, лучше бы перевести так: «Мы вознаграждаем авторов вопросов и пересчитываем репутацию!»

Comment: @YellowSky, чем лучше? Репутация уже пересчитана, а "пересчитываем" предполагает, что пересчёт продолжается.

Comment: @Qwertiy - Ну, так значит, что на момент написания оригинала на английском пересчёт всё ещё продолжался. Или, по-вашему, «are being recalculated» – это не настоящее продолженное время (Present Continious), обозначающее действие, длящееся в момент речи? Оригинал однозначно говорит о том, что пересчёт шёл в тот момент, когда оригинал писали.

Comment: На самом деле это проблема. Т.к. текст изначально мог быть другим. Я не уверен, что видел в самом начале именно этот текст.

Answer (score 1):

Эта запятая лишняя и надо её убрать.

Вот два источника с правилами, подтверждающими это мнение:

> Также не нужны запятые, если деепричастие выражает не дополнительное действие, а оттенок основного

<sup>Источник: http://ktvd.ru/obosoblenie-deeprichastnych-oborotov/</sup>

> **Примечание.** Одиночное деепричастие или деепричастный оборот не обособляется:
>
> 1) если деепричастный оборот (обычно со значением обстоятельства образа действия) тесно связан по содержанию со сказуемым и образует смысловой центр высказывания: *Она сидела чуть откинув голову* (Марк.) — указывается, что она не просто сидела, а сидела с откинутой головой; *Жили Артамоновы ни с кем не знакомясь* (М. Г.) — важно, что жили без всяких знакомств; *Это упражнение делают* ***стоя на вытянутых носках*** — смысл сообщения в том, каким образом делают упражнение; *Старик шёл* ***прихрамывая на правую ногу**;* *Студенты приобретают знания* ***не только слушая лекции, но и выполняя практические работы**;* *Писал он обычно* ***наклонив голову**;* ***Не унижая себя*** *говорю, а говорю с болью в сердце* (М. Г.); *Огромного роста, редкой силы, волосатый, он ходил по земле* ***наклоня голову,*** *как бык* (М. Г.); *Яков сидел* ***опустив ноги*** (М. Г.).

<sup>Источник: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Если это предложение должно иметь смысл приведённого английского, то для деепричастия ошибочно выбраны *время* (прошедшее) и *вид* (совершенный). В исходном варианте оно грамматически неверно. Деепричастие здесь должно *раскрывать содержание* основного действия (*в чем заключается* поощрение пользователей, задающих вопросы), будучи с ним *одновременным*. Это упрощённая, более лаконичная форма предложения:

> Мы поощряем/вознаграждаем авторов вопросов тем, что пересчит**ываем**
>   им репутацию.

*Если деепричастие называет одновременное действие, оно может стоять и до, и после сказуемого. https://www.examen.ru/add/manual/school-subjects/languages/russian/slovar/deeprichastie/*

Соответственно, при замене второй части приведённого предложения на деепричастный оборот проблем не возникает, и правильный вариант исходного предложения может быть таким:

> Мы поощряем авторов вопросов, пересчит**ывая** [им] репутацию.

Comment: Нет, не такой смысл. Эта та плашка, которая висит и на этом сайте. Смысл такой: раньше за вопрос давали по 5 баллов репутации, а теперь по 10, при этом прошлая репутация уже пересчиталась (причём ретроспективно) и об этом висит уведомление. Репутация уже пересчитана, причём пересчитана один раз и в дальнейшем не будет, так что прошедшее время и совершенный вид: "пересчитав репутацию". А вот "вознаграждаем" или "вознаградили" - немного другой вопрос. На мой взгляд, в настоящем времени красивее.